# read each lines of a file - Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, sqlcmd

I've to write a batch script. The script read the lines of an input files and for each line execute a sqlcmd.
But when i execute my script it's doesn't work like i want, in fact it's doesn't make the job...

My batch script :

```
    @echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set Chemin=C:\users\documents\Communication\Test\MSG_IN

 set NomFichierU=UHMSO_1
 set user=admin
 set pwd=admin
 set db=DTBASE_001

cd /d %Chemin%
set nomfic=%NomFichierU%
set HHMMSS=A
set HHMMSS=%LTIME:~0,2%%LTIME:~3,2%%LTIME:~6,2%
for %%f IN (%NomFichierU%*.txt) DO (
    for /f tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= %%l IN (%%f) DO (
      echo test
      REM echo %%l
      ECHO %%G
      set nomficr=%%a 
      set nomfic=!nomficr:~0,-1!.tmp
      REN %%a !nomfic!
      rem executer sript MHUHMS.sql avec sqlplus
      sqlcmd -S MILCS02 -U %user% -P %pwd% -d %db% -i c:\users\documents\SQL\MHUHMS.sql
      move !nomfic! SLD_SLDHI\SAVE
    )
)
```

And the MHUHMS.SQL just make update in database.
My problem is when i'm execute the batch script, it's just place me into the folder 'Chemin', but i want it read the file like UHMSO_1_XXXXX.txt. And after, for each lines of my files, it runs my sql script.

My error at this moment : 
The system cannot find the file UHMSO_1*.txt.

And i'm palced in the folder...

If someone have any idea, because i'm not really good in batch script... and i don't know too if my sqlcmd is correct or not...

Thank's for help !

EDIT: After help from wOxxOm & MichaelS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after troubleshooting it in the chat discussion let's sum up the issues:

- `for /f` can't be used with wildcards. Enumerate the files in an additional outer `for` loop and use the loop variable in `for /f`
- the text files were in UTF-16 encoding, use `for ... ('type "filename"') ...`
- `sqlcmd` can only see normal batch variables, not loop variables like `%%l` so [pass it with `-v`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx)
- all lines with `nomfic`, `%%a` and `%%G` aren't needed
- use `cd /d c:\some\path` to actually change the working drive AND path.
  Or better even `pushd c:\some\path` + `popd` to save and restore the previous working folder.
- `move` the file only after having processed all its lines
- `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` isn't needed for the posted code fragment

---

```
set Chemin=C:\users\documents\Communication\Test\MSG_IN
set NomFichierU=UHMSO_1
set HHMMSS=%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%

pushd %Chemin%
for /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b "%NomFichierU%*.txt"') DO (
    for /f tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= %%l IN ('type "%%f"') DO (
        sqlcmd -S MILCS02 -U %user% -P %pwd% -d %db% ^
               -i c:\users\documents\SQL\MHUHMS.sql -v l ="%%l"
    )
    move "%%f" "SLD_SLDHI\SAVE\%%f.%HHMMSS%"
)
popd
pause
```

P.S. In case the file names can contain spaces use `usebackq` and quote the variable:

```
for /f usebackq^ tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^= %%l IN ("%%f") DO (
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93506/discussion-between-woxxom-and-s-guillaume).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there are more errors in the code but one is definitely that you are missing `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`. You are using the delayed expansion (e.g. `!nomfic!`) but `!...!` is useless without `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Thank's for your contribution, i add that !

Comment: Would you please also update your code in the question? I guess the code still doesn't work?

Comment: Yes ... It don't work... But now it's different than before. Before i was placed on the directory 'Chemin'. Now i'm at the directory at the beginning, where i execute my .bat. So i thing it's a good thing... I'm update my code